# Supremum of sets of extended reals

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, proof-verification

Hi everyone I'd like to know if following is really correct, looks kinda cumbersome, I think, it is for the great quantity of cases to analyze. To be honest I don't know if this is the better way to do it. but I cannot see other approach.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

**Definitions**: Let $E$ be a subset of the extended real numbers $\overline { \mathbb{R}}$. Then we define the least upper bound of $E$ by the following rule:

1) If $E$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., $+\infty$ and $- \infty$ are not elements in $E$), then we let $\text{sup } E$ as is define in $\mathbb{R}$.

2) If $E$ is contains $+\infty$, then we set $\text{sup } E:= +\infty$

3) If $E$ does not contain $+\infty$ but does contain $-\infty$, then we set  $\text{sup } E:= \text{sup } ( E- \{ -\infty \})$.

We define the infimum by the formula $\text{inf } E:=-\text{sup } (-E)$ where $-E := \{  -x: x\in E\}$

**Theorem**: Let $E$ be a subset of the extended real numbers. Then the following statements are true:

$(a)$ For all $x\in E$ we have $x\le \text{sup } E$ and  $x\ge \text{inf } E$

$(b)$ Suppose $M$ is an upper bound for $E$, i.e., $x \le M$ for all $x\in E$. Then we have $\,\text{sup } E \le M$.

$(c)$ Suppose $M$ is a lower bound for $E$, i.e., $x \ge M$ for all $x\in E$. Then we have $\,\text{inf } E \ge M$.

Proof: Let $S = \text{sup } E$ and let $L= \text{inf } E$

$(a)$

If $S= -\infty$, then $E$ is empty and the result is vacuously true. When $S = +\infty$ by definition we have $x\le S$ for all  $x\in \overline { \mathbb{R}}$, in particular for all the $x \in E$. If $S\in \mathbb{R}$, $E$ does not contain $+\infty$  and thus $E$ only contains element in $\mathbb{R}$ or $-\infty$ and in either case the result follows.

So let $-E := \{  -x: x\in E\}$. And for what we've proved above, we have $\,-x\le \text{sup } (-E)$ for all $-x\in -E$, which means $L=-\text{sup } (-E) \le x$ and since $-x\in -E$ iff $x\in E$, we're done.

$(b)$

(1) Suppose $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, i.e., $+\infty$ and $- \infty$ are not elements in $E$. If $S = -\infty$, it follows that $E= \emptyset$ and so $S \le M$ where  $M$ can be every element in $\overline { \mathbb{R}}$. If $S = +\infty$, then $E$ is unbounded and then $M\notin \mathbb{R}$ (otherwise we have a contradiction). Thus either $M= -\infty$  or $M= +\infty$; If $M = -\infty$ and by definition of upper bound, for an arbitrary $x\in E$ we have $x \le -\infty$, but this implies $x= -\infty$ which contradicts the fact that $E$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, and If $M = +\infty$ then clearly is an upper bound and $S \le M$. Now in the case when $S\in \mathbb{R}$, we have that if $M\in \mathbb{R}$ the result follows from the properties of the lub in $\mathbb{R}$. When $M\notin \mathbb{R}$ by the same argument as before we know that $M\not= -\infty$ so $M = +\infty$ and by definition $S\le M$.

(2) Now suppose $+\infty \in E$. Since $M$ is an upper bound for $E$ and  we assume that $+\infty \in E$ thus $+\infty \le M$, which means $M= +\infty$. Thus, $S\le M$.

(3) When $E$ does not contain $+\infty$ but does contain $-\infty$, we thus have $S= \text{sup } (E^{*})$; where  $E^*=E- \{ -\infty \}$. Thus falls under case (1).

$(c)$ It follows from $(b)$ and the fact that $\text{inf } E:=-\text{sup } (-E)$ where $-E := \{  -x: x\in E\}$.

Thanks :)

Comment: Aside: It might be easier to show $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ has least upper bounds, then prove the least upper bound satisfies the properties you list for $\sup E$. Especially if you find an easy way to show it has least upper bounds: e.g. an order isomorphism between $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: It's a pity, I don't see some of the terms yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good.  The only things that jumped out at me were the fact that

1. $S=-\infty$ does not imply that $E=\emptyset$; it could also be the case that $E=\{-\infty\}$.
2. In (b)(1), you haven't considered the case where $E=\emptyset$.

Other than that, it seems pretty reasonable, given the machinery that you're using. (As Hurkyl noted, you can define the extended reals as the order completion of $\mathbb{R}$, in which case everything flows easily.  But that's a different branch of mathematics altogether.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. A fortunately both mistakes can be easily fix them.